# JavaScript ES6 in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am trying to run a Javascript code in Internet Explorer 11.

It not working with arrow functions or ``, however I need these sintax because I would like to work more comfortable and do not have some issues with this.

I trying with Babel at top and in the end of the page, but I always have the same error in IE11:

**Character not valid**

This error is because `${}`

It is the library that I am using:

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.4/polyfill.min.js" integrity="sha512-pgx+g4+yrNG/DhUEosN7ontsnk2WayfSuK1Fmy2GrqNi8ktUpIlTpKj80dCLyoEELA6c6m5otWP9RM/lq5UTQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What I am doing bad?

Comment: How are you running your code through Babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using babel like this should be used mostly for prototyping. As official [babel setup guide](https://babeljs.io/setup) says:

> Compiling in the browser has a fairly limited use case, so if you are working on a production site you should be precompiling your scripts server-side. [...]

If you still want to use babel in current way, remember that you need to mark your script tag as `text/babel`.

```html
<script type="text/babel">
    // Your script content
</script>
```

I would reccomend using some kind of build system like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which configured correctly will execute babel scripts for you.

You can use Babel as a CLI or require hook too, but for that I am sending you to the official [babel setup documentation](https://babeljs.io/setup).

Comment: Thanks men, it is the problem, I am using Django templates with HTML and Vanilla JS, without compilation. Anyway, with your method it worked.